# Get product_id of associated product added in cart

Tags: configurable-product, associate-products

I have a configurable product and I want to capture the data of the associated product which is added to cart.

http://manoolia.dmcs-online.com/zig-zag-configurable?___store=english&___from_store=english

On this example, when you chose green and add it to cart, a popup will display with the red image(configurable product image). I want to get the associated product image etc.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show simple product thumbnail in shopping cart than you can change configuration on below path:

you will find this option in shopping cart section as define below.

system->configuration->sales->checkout->shopping cart tab.

[image: system->configuration->sales->checkout->shoppingcart]

Comment: If you found answer helpful than please accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but although similar, this is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract::getChildren`, you should be able to use it to get the first child of a configurable which will be it's associated simple, then get whatever data you require.

Something like the following:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/image');

//However you get the quoteItem, it goes here!
$quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');

$imageUrl = $helper->init($quoteItem->getProduct(), 'small_image');

if ($quoteItem->getData('product_type') == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {

    $children = $quoteItem->getChildren();
    $childQuoteItem = reset($children);
    if ($childQuoteItem) {
        $imageUrl = $helper->init($childQuoteItem->getProduct(), 'small_image');
    }
}
```

Comment: This code gets all children?

Comment: Calling `reset` on it will get the first child, which will be the `simple` of the `configurable`

Comment: Tried your code but it throws an error. Also tried with $_product->getChildren() but doesn't get any.

Comment: Product get children willnae work. What error is thrown?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function setFinalPrice() on a non-object in /home/manoolia/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item/Abstract.php on line 89

Comment: The code is on header.phtml http://prntscr.com/5y296q